# Using Portable Class Library with Webrequest and WP8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library

I have a problem to which I can't find any solution, and I find it hard to believe I'm the only one getting this error.

I have this piece of C# code in a Portable Class Library

```
static public void GetAnimeListFromWeb(ObservableCollection<AnimeViewModel> collection, string Url, string encodedLogin = "")
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Url);
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = encodedLogin;

        IAsyncResult asyncResult = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback( s => {
            WebResponse response = (s.AsyncState as WebRequest).EndGetResponse(s);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

            IEnumerable<AnimeViewModel> result = ParseAnimeXML(doc);

            collection = (ObservableCollection<AnimeViewModel>)result;

        }), request);
    }
```

When I compile this, it builds, and the code also works in a small console program I wrote to test it. However, when testing in a Windows Phone 8 app it crashes on

```
WebResponse response = (s.AsyncState as WebRequest).EndGetResponse(s);
```

It throws an ArgumentException. When I inspected the 's' variable, it said the AsyncWaitHandle gave a NotSupportedException.

My question is then, how can I make a proper Webrequest that would work on all platforms?

EDIT: Maybe it is useful to note that I'm targeting .NET 4.5, SL4 and higher, WP7 and higher and .NET for Windows Store Apps

Comment: I'm unable to repro this. Ignore the AsyncWaitHandle that's a red herring, and isn't related (we just don't support waiting on async result). Is that the exact repro above? Is the ArgumentException actually coming from the EndGetResponse? It throws ArgumentException when you pass an IAsyncResult that isn't the exactly one from the request.BeginGetResponse method.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the code it crashes on, tested it multiple times with different syntax but it all crashes on that line saying the AsyncWaitHandle threw an NotSupportedException

Comment: Let's take a step back. Can you trying repro'ing in a standalone Windows Phone 8 project to rule out Portable Class Libraries? Does this occur in the emulator? If so which emulator, Windows Phone 7 or Windows Phone 8?

Comment: I found the issue when investigating the error somewhat better. It crashed because the Authorization header got an empty string, which apparently makes it crash.

And I'm indeed using an emulator, the WP8 WXGA one.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you'll need to use latest Asyc/Await concept to perform this task like DownloadStringAsync. Because Async/Await is the only supported mechanism in Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8. However, when you use this code and build it for multiple platforms, compiler will handle the intricacies of different platform and produce the required code.

Comment: That's not correct. BeginXXX and EndXX *is* supported in Windows Phone 8. This does not have anything to do with the compiler either, the compiler produces the same code regardless of whether using Windows 8, Phone 8 or Portable.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I was in wrong assumption. I thought the only method for async call is Async/await.

Comment: If you have a pcl with windows phone 7.5 and up you can use this to add async support: Microsoft.Bcl.Async (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/11/22/10361314.aspx?PageIndex=3)